# Best way of getting the row just added. Heroku + Node + Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, node.js, heroku, express

What is the best way of getting the row that was just added, I am working with Heroku, Node and Postgres, and Expressjs. I want to be able to do something like this.

```
app.post( '/', function( req, res ){
      client.query("INSERT into ..", function( err, result ){
            res.send( result.id );
      });
});
```

Ideally the callback would have information about the row that it just entered in but the content of it just an object that looks like

```
{ rows:[] }
```

Is there a good way of getting that row that I just added, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [`INSERT ... RETURNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html):

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted. This is primarily useful for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial sequence number. However, any expression using the table's columns is allowed. The syntax of the `RETURNING` list is identical to that of the output list of SELECT.

So something like this:

```
client.query('insert into your_table (...) values (...) returning *', function(err, result) {
    // ...
});
```

should get you the newly inserted row in your callback function.